# iOS JSON parsing returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am parsing a JSON that looks like this:

```
    [
  {
  "Country of Build":"Belgium",
  "Shipbuilder":" Boelwerf",
  "Hull #":" 1487",
  "Ship Name":" Methania",
  "Shipowner":" Distrigas",
  "Operator":" Exmar",
  "Delivery":"Oct-78",
  "Flag":" Belgium",
  "Class":" LR",
  "Power Plant":" Steam",
  "HP":" 45,000",
  "Speed": 19.0,
  "Cargo System":" GT NO 85",
  "# of Tanks": 5,
  "Capacity ":" 131,235",
  "Price":
  },
  {
  "Country of Build":"China",
  "Shipbuilder":" Cosco Dalian",
  "Hull #":"  ",
  "Ship Name":"  ",
  "Shipowner":" CNOOC Energy",
  "Operator":"  ",
  "Delivery":" 1Q15",
  "Flag":"  ",
  "Class":" AB/CC",
  "Power Plant":" DFDE",
  "HP":"  ",
  "Speed":  ,
  "Cargo System":" GT NO 96",
  "# of Tanks": 4,
  "Capacity ":" 28,000",
  "Price":81
  }, ---8000 more lines--- }]
```

I have a custom object in which I want to parse the objects into, which looks like this: 
.h

```
@interface LNGVessel : NSObject

@property NSString *countryOfBuild;
@property NSString *shipBuilder;
@property NSString *hull;
@property NSString *shipName;
@property NSString *shipOwner;
@property NSString *shipOperator;
@property NSString *delivery;
@property NSString *flag;
@property NSString *shipClass;
@property NSString *powerPlant;
@property NSString *hp;
@property NSString *speed;
@property NSString *cargoSystem;
@property NSString *numOfTanks;
@property NSString *capacity;
@property NSString *price;

-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;

@end
```

and a .m like this

```
-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
    self.countryOfBuild = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Country of Build"];
    self.shipBuilder = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Shipbuilder"];
    self.hull = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Hull #"];
    self.shipName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Ship Name"];
    self.shipOwner = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Shipowner"];
    self.shipOperator = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Operator"];
    self.delivery = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Delivery"];
    self.flag = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Flag"];
    self.shipClass = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Class"];
    self.powerPlant = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Power Plant"];
    self.hp = [dictionary objectForKey:@"HP"];
    self.speed = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Speed"];
    self.cargoSystem = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Cargo System"];
    self.numOfTanks = [dictionary objectForKey:@"# of Tanks"];
    self.capacity = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Capacity"];
    self.price = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Price"];

}
return self;
}
```

Now, I have a local .json file with about 8000 lines, 450-ish objects. 
I parse them to an array in a UIMutableArray category, which looks like this:

```
//.h
 @interface NSMutableArray (LNGVessels)
+(NSMutableArray*)allVessels;

@end

//.m

    @implementation NSMutableArray (LNGVessels)

+(NSMutableArray*)allVessels{
    NSMutableArray *array;

    NSString* pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vessels" ofType: @"json"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];

    id JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [JSONArray objectEnumerator];
    NSDictionary* item;
    while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {

        LNGVessel *vessel = [[LNGVessel alloc]initWithDict:item];
        [array addObject:vessel];
    }
    return array;
}
@end
```

The problem? this doesn't work, it always returns null. I have logged the NSData object, which returned all the json contents (in hex)

I thought that it might be the JSON's fault, so I checked http://jsonlint.com/ and pasted the whole thing. I got an error on

```
Parse error on line 18:
...      "Price":     },    {        "Co
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

which suggests I need to fix that. But still, I would assume that my code would just insert nil for that argument.

Oh, and I realised that JSONSerilaziation got an error parameter. That logs

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 376.) UserInfo=0x170463380 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 376.}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON should be

```
{
...
"Price":null
...
}
```

According to Apple documentation:

> **JSONObjectWithData:options:error:**
>
> ***error*** If an error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object that
>   describes the problem.
>
> ***Return Value*** A Foundation object from the JSON data in data, or nil if
>   an error occurs.

Setting `error` parameter to `nil` might not be helpful at times like this.

Comment: Its the json docs fault? Is there any tool to mass insert nil objects to empty arguements, doing so to possibly 8000 lines would be a pain.

Comment: I guess it'd be better you make sure that's the problem, first test your code with smaller and totally valid JSON object, if it is ok then sharpen your regex skills :) you can look for invalid patterns and replace them with regex as you know.

Comment: I pasted the source into EXCEL, exported it as CSV, parsed CSV to JSON, somewhere along the way, null's got inserted instead of nothings. Code works now, JSON was the sinner.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, your JSON data is invalid. In that case

```
id JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

just returns `nil`. (It does not omit or skip invalid entries.)

And you also forgot to `alloc`+`init` the `NSMutableArray *array`.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    LNGVessel *vessel = [[LNGVessel alloc]initWithDict:dict];
    ....
}
```

Comment: I did, but some other SO question I came by suggested using fast enumeration like such, so I assumed it was better.